# Vectorized approach to extract the rows of the end-point array that contains the elements of another array

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, vectorization

What the title says. I am looking for a fast and pythonic approach to extract the rows of the end-point array `A` that contains the elements of another array `v`

A simple example of what I want to achieve is as follows:

Input:

```
A = [[ 4  9]
     [15 19]
     [20 28]
     [31 37]
     [43 43]]    
v =  [ 0  1  2  3 11 12 13 14 26 29 30 31 43]
```

Because A is an end-pint array, which means in each row the first element and the second element represent the start and the end of an interval. Since only the intervals of `[20 28]`, `[31 37]`, and `[43 43]` contain the elements in v(in this case `26,31 and 43` are contained in the intervals created by the endpoint array `A`),  the desired output is:

```
[[20 28]
 [31 37]
 [43 43]]
```

---

The following is the code to generate the actual input arrays:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)

size = 32000
base_arr = np.arange(size)*10

t1 = np.random.randint(0,6, size)+base_arr
t2 = np.random.randint(5,10, size)+base_arr

A = np.vstack((t1,t2)).T
v = np.sort(np.random.randint(0,10,3*size)+np.repeat(base_arr,3))
```

---

Thank you in advance

---

EDIT: added more details to the explanation

Comment: Related: [Find if a sorted array of floats contains numbers in a certain range efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40261135/find-if-a-sorted-array-of-floats-contains-numbers-in-a-certain-range-efficiently).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Approach #1**

We can use [`np.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) to get the left and right positional indices for the start and end elements on each row against the `v` values and look for non-matching ones, which would indicate that the particular row has at least one element within those bounds. Hence, we could simply do -

```
A[np.searchsorted(v,A[:,0],'left')!=np.searchsorted(v,A[:,1],'right')]
```

**Approach #2**

Another way would be to use the left-positioned indices to index into `v` and then see if they are lesser than the right end-points. Hence, it would be -

```
idx = np.searchsorted(v,A[:,0],'left')
out = A[(idx<len(v)) & (v[idx.clip(max=len(v)-1)]<=A[:,1])]
```

Note that this assumes `v` to be sorted and inputs as arrays. If `v` isn't sorted already, we need to sort it and then feed it in.

Timings on bigger dataset at my end -

```
In [65]: %timeit A[np.searchsorted(v,A[:,0],'left')!=np.searchsorted(v,A[:,1],'right')]
2 ms ± 10.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [66]: %%timeit
    ...: idx = np.searchsorted(v,A[:,0],'left')
    ...: out = A[(idx<len(v)) & (v[idx.clip(max=len(v)-1)]<=A[:,1])]
1.32 ms ± 7.87 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. By far the fastest approach among the already good approches

Comment: @Divakar I just looped the answers over `range(400)`, I found that  `for i in [5,29,130,139,146,150,156,178,295,313,315,337,342]: np.random.seed(i)`, the outputs from approach 1 and approach 2 are different.

Comment: @Divakar, in the testing ground with 400 iterations yes there could be duplicates. But in the places I actually want to apply my function to, no there shouldn't be duplicates. And if there is, then I will use `v = np.unique(v)` to remove them.

Comment: @mathguy Yup, I needed to check for one condition there. Edited app#2.

Comment: @Divakar Just checked it with different kinds of `v`, so far so good. Really appreciate your follow-up

Answer (score 1):

Compare along a third dimension

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[ 4,  9],
              [15, 19],
              [20, 28],
              [31, 37],
              [43, 43]])    
v =  np.array([ 0,  1,  2,  3, 11, 12, 13, 14, 26, 29, 30, 31, 43])
between = np.logical_and(v >= a[:,0,None], v <= a[:,1,None])
print(a[between.any(-1)])

>>>
[[20 28]
 [31 37]
 [43 43]]
>>>
```

Comment: Unfortunately mine *blows up* on the larger arrays with a MemoryError

Comment: Actually I noticed that in my pc too. I wonder if there are ways to do it in your approach without creating an extra dimension. If it is possible, then the function should be a lot less memory-hungry.

Comment: The extra dimension is needed to make this work, it allows [Broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html).  Searchsorted is the way to go.  I got stuck and misled myself when I read the term *vectorized*.

Answer (score 1):

I do not consider this wholly Pythonic, but it is at least O(n).

```
def find_bounding_intervals(A, v):
    rows = []
    i = 0
    for row in A:
        while all(v[i] < row):
            i += 1
        if row[0] <= v[i] <= row[1]:
            rows.append(row)
    return np.array(rows)

A = np.array([[ 4,  9],
              [15, 19],
              [20, 28],
              [31, 37],
              [43, 43]])
v =  np.array([ 0,  1,  2,  3, 11, 12, 13, 14, 26, 29, 30, 31, 43])
print(find_bounding_intervals(A, v))
```

My low-end laptop grinds out a solution in ~0.28s for the much larger data defined in your question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Didnt know the `all()` built-in function exists up until now

Comment: Just used your code to experiment on whether a `numba`-njitted version of your implementation can beat the vectorized version. I found that in terms of sheer performance, the `numba` version is the fastest. I will post it down below.

Answer (score 1):

```
from numba import njit
@njit
def find_bounding_intervals(A, v):
    rows_L = []
    rows_R = []

    i = 0
    for row in range(A.shape[0]):
        while v[i] < A[row,0] and v[i] < A[row,1]:
            i += 1
        if A[row,0] <= v[i] <= A[row,1]:
            rows_L.append(A[row,0])
            rows_R.append(A[row,1])
    return np.array([rows_L, rows_R]).T
```

Although this implementation is technically not a vectorized function, it is indeed the fastest across almost all sizes of `n`.

I should make it clear that the algorithm comes from @brentertainer